# .net word interop: word.Documents.Open returns null

Tags: c#, office-interop

I'm using .net .4.6.1 and trying to do a mail merge. When i run the following code, which has a valid path to a word (.doc) document, it returns null.

C#

```
object fileName = pathToDocument;

doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What is the actual file path passed to the `Open` method?

Comment: hiya,  fileName = @"\\server\blah\Automated\xx.doc";

I don’t think it’s a path issue because I can paste it into fileExplorer, and it works, ALSO, it works on other machines. I believe it’s possibly got something to do with the OS / Word version. In short, would I be better using OpenXml, to resolve this and have a more-future proof resolution?   Thanks, Chris

Comment: Word deals  with local files only. You need to copy the file locally and then use the Word object model to open it.

Comment: The server (let's call it machine C) is where we store the word docs. If i run the code on machine serverA, the "Open" method doesn't return anything, yet it does seem to if i run on serverB. ..I really don't want to be installing Word on machines if i can get away with. As far as i can see, i use OpenXML..the advantages are: 1) not having to install Word on additional machines. 2) Not locking the word docs.  Has anyone else migrated away from interop for these reasons? Thanks, Chris

Comment: It depends on what you actually need to do with files. [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) is a way to go if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `Open` method is really confusing but it can be treated with more of a common sense approach, try something like this adjusting the file path of your document ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileName = "c:\\temp\\Test.docx";

    var wdApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    var wdDocument = wdApplication.Documents.Open(fileName);

    Console.WriteLine(wdDocument.Words.Count);

    wdDocument.Close();
    wdApplication.Quit();
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the OP code and yours?

Answer (score 0):

Word deals with local files only. You need to copy the file locally and then use the Word object model to open it.

The [Documents.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open) method doesn't require the `ref` keyword for passing parameters:

```
doc = word.Documents.Open(pathToDocument,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```